# Android studio 3.6 Layout editor lags when displaying Button attributes

Tags: android, android-studio-3.6

Basically every time i try to Select Button or anything that extends `Button` (`AppCompatButton`, `MaterialButton`)

Android studio freezes for few seconds when selecting Button in layout editor. every other component works normally (i think so).

On new project this behavior is not present.

p.s. 3.5.{latest} also had this issue but it was less annoying since xml editor and layout editor was two separate things.

Simply putting marker on anything that is inside xml button declaration (in my layout) causes this lag of (3-4 seconds). In that period of time i can't use Android studio at all.

So my question is what could cause such behavior and how could i avoid it?

Comment: Happens for me also.. Im Using Macbook Pro.

Comment: @PrakashBala When i was switching from Android studio 3.6 to 4.0 just to test if it might address the issue, i had moment when project sync is failing. At that moment there were no lags selecting the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone facing AS freeze while editing XML or editing Material components like Button, do the following steps:

Open Layout Editor -> Click on Attributes Tab -> Settings Icon -> Will show list of options, disable all options with "Attributes", like "All Attributes", "Common Attributes", "Declared Attributes"

Will solve the issue for now.

**UPDATE:**
Issue is already reported and AS team is working on the fix:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139716861
Actual fix requires new AS release or 4.1 canary 10 (as per AS Team comment).

Comment: Just checked it. Working solution. Since there was no explanation on why this could happen and how this could be avoided, I just accept your answer.

Comment: @Alpha It is known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139716861
Already reported, it is being fixed, as per their comment "Should be fixed in 4.1 canary 10". Everyone has to wait for new AS for actual fix.